# Change permissions for files in S3 using Dragonfly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, fog, dragonfly-gem

in my rails project i use dragonfly for uploading files and store them in S3.

initially i pass {'x-amz-acl' => 'private'} for uploaded files and use private urls with expiration date.

is there an easy way to change it to 'public-read' after the file was uploaded to S3?

Answer (score 0):

I use the `aws/s3` gem. Handling permissions can be done with something like this:

```
S3Object.store(
    'kiss.jpg',
    data,
    'marcel',
    :access => :public_read
  )
```

In your case, you would use `S3Object.find` and then change the policy. The gem is documented [here](http://amazon.rubyforge.org/).